# Save JSON file with different id Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, save

First I parsed JSON with this function and structure:

```
func loadJson{
        guard let documentsDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {return}
        let fileUrl = documentsDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("Persons.json")
        do{

            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)

                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

                let res = try jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)

                for (id,item) in  res.fields {

                  self.all.append(Item(id:id,timestampValue:item.timestampValue))}

            print(res)

        } catch{

            print(error)

        }
    }


struct Root: Codable  
{

 let fields: [String: Field]

 let createTime, updateTime: String

struct Field: Codable

{

 let timestampValue: String

}

struct Item {

   let id,timestampValue: String

}
```

I added data from picker into parsed array: all.
And I get this output from array:

```
App.Item(id: "John Doe", timestampValue: "30-03-2020"), App.Item(id: "Erik Martin", timestampValue: "2020-03-30"), App.Item(id: "Michael Lindros", timestampValue: "2020-03-30"), App.Item(id: "Henry Cup", timestampValue: "2020-03-30"), App.Item(id: "Oliver John", timestampValue: "2020-03-30")]
```

I need to save JSON back in this format:
Every username id and timestamp value is different, and array can be with one or 100 username id's

```
{

  "fields": {

      "John Doe": {

      "timestampValue": "2020-02-04"

    },
     "Erik Martin ": {

      "timestampValue": "2020-02-05"

    }},

  "createTime": "2020-02-04",

  "updateTime": "2020-02-04"

}
```

I try multiple stack, google manuals with json but without right output.
Big thanks for any suggestions.
My one test from milion :

```
func saveToJsonFile() {


        guard let documentDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

        let fileUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("Persons.json")
            var paramCollection = [Any]()

            var dataCollection = [Any]()

            var index = 0

            var dictX = [String:Any]()

             for (data) in dict {

             dictX = [componentArrayId[index]:["timestampValue":listTs[index]]]

                dataCollection.append(dictX)

                index += 1    

                }

                paramCollection.append(dataCollection)

                let finalParameter = ["fields":paramCollection]

        do {


            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: finalParameter , options: [])

                  try data.write(to: fileUrl, options: [])

                        } catch {

                            print(error)

                        }

                          print("DATA UPLOADED")

            }}
```

Comment: Try `JSONEncoder` instead of `JSONSerialization`

Comment: Hi @Koen it is working but I have problem to add create and update time correctly.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Please submit a new question about your time problem.

Comment: I cant create new Q...thank you for your previous answer

Comment: Why can't you create a new question?

Comment: I get :You have reached your question limit
We ask that you wait 5 days before asking again

Comment: In that case you will have to wait. Don't post follow-up questions in the comments, it could potentially extend your waiting time.

Comment: ok..thank you for help and info